# User defined function returns value error which should be string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a file where there is a calendar in each sheet and cells represent the time interval on that day. I have multiple worksheets identical to each other, however the first worksheet is the one to display info. Other worksheets are for each group member to mark if they are not available (NA) or remotely available (R) for that time.

I want my function to check every worksheet for the same cell coordinate (because every sheet is identical and cells represent the time on that day), if they have any `R` or `NA` written in them. If not, it should output `AA` for all available on the original cell where the function is written.

If there are some people remotely available, then it should output `AA(!)` for all available but some remotely, and show who are the ones that are remotely available in the comment of that cell.

If there are any `NA`s then the output should also be `NA` and show who are the ones that are not available as a comment on the original cell.

I keep getting `#VALUE!` error and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
Function Checkdate(a) 'a is the selected cell, which is the same cell as the function is written
    Dim ac
    ac = a.Column
    Dim ar
    ar = a.Row
    Dim names
    names = Array("person1", "person 2", "person 3")
    Dim avlb As String 'avlb is the availabiltiy situation and later will be the result of the function
    avlb = "AA"
    Dim rnames As String 'the string variable where names will be stored who are remotely available
    rnames = ""
    Dim nanames As String 'the string variable where names will be stored who are not available
    nanames = ""
    For Each Name In names
        If Worksheets(Name).Cells(ar, ac).Value = "R" Then
    avlb = "AA(!)"
            rnames = rnames & " " & Name
        End If
        If Worksheets(Name).Cells(ar, ac).Value = "NA" Then
            avlb = "NA"
        nanames = nanames & " " & Name
        End If
    Next Name
    Checkdate(a) = avlb
    If avlb = "AA(!)" Then
        a.AddComment = "Remotely available:" & rnames
    ElseIf avlb = "NA" Then
        a.AddComment = "Not available:" & nanames
    Else
        a.Comment.Delete
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Begin by replacing **//** with **'** as the beginning of a VBA comment.

Comment: Hello, thanks. The comments were not actually in the code i put them here just to be more clear. i edited them now

Comment: Try replacing your `.Value`s with `.Text`, not sure of the underlying reason but this has worked for me in the past

Comment: Do you expect your function to return something? What do you expect from this (strange) line: `Checkdate(a) = avlb`? You call the function recursively and try to compare its return (the function is not designed to return something) with some string...

Comment: Yes, I expect my function to return the availability situation stored in `avlb`, which could be AA, AA(!) or NA. I changed `.Value` `.Text` btw and it did not help unfortunately.

Comment: I guess you are calling this from a worksheet. If yes then you will get #Value error becuase you are trying to add a comment in a UDF. You can replicate this issue with a small function `Function Checkdate(a As Range) As String: a.AddComment = "Remotely available:": Checkdate = "Something": End Function`

Comment: Indeed it gives a #VALUE! error as well, however it also adds a blank comment.
EDIT: the main code works if i remove the comments! but i also need to add a comment to show who are the ones not available, how can i do so?

Comment: In order to make a function to return something, you must build your function like this: `Function Checkdate(a) As String`. And take  care to return somewhere (in the function) its result. The return line should be like this: `Checkdate  = avlb` If you intend to do that on the line `Checkdate(a) = avlb`, you practically recursivelly call the function for the same argument and make a strange comparison. It may stay in an infinite loop...

Comment: FaneDuru corrected that thanks! SiddharthRout  reading now!

Comment: You also must declare the function parameter. Since you use `c.Column`, it should be a range... `Function Checkdate(a As Range) As String`

Comment: Does now the function return what you need? Besides the error raised by reasons well described by @Siddharth Rout ... Try comment the lines regarding the comment creation and see what happens.

Comment: @FaneDuru corrected that as well, thanks a lot! Unfortunately it does not add comment, if i remove the comment-adding section it works well.

Comment: As @Siddharth Rout well explained, you cannot perform such an operation from a sheet function! You can use a sheet event (change, for instance) to do what you need if the changed cell is the  one you follow and it has a specific value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Indeed it gives a #VALUE! error as well, however it also adds a blank comment. EDIT: the main code works if i remove the comments! but i also need to add a comment to show who are the ones not available, how can i do so? – Miraç Mert Pelister 8 mins ago

The problem is with this

```
If avlb = "AA(!)" Then
    a.AddComment = "Remotely available:" & rnames
ElseIf avlb = "NA" Then
    a.AddComment = "Not available:" & nanames
Else
    a.Comment.Delete
End If
```

Try this: (Thanks to @T.M for drawing my attention towards it.)

The correct way to add a comment is

```
With Rng
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Text Text:="Your text"
End With
```

Incorporating it in your code.

```
If avlb = "AA(!)" Then
    With a
        '<~~ Check if cell already has a comment
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete 
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:="Remotely available:" & "sid"
    End With
ElseIf avlb = "NA" Then
    With a
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:="Not available:" & "sid"
    End With
Else
    If Not a.Comment Is Nothing Then a.Comment.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I have read what you shared, so i understand it is not possible to create a comment with the udf. But I couldn't understand if there's a workaround or not. What do you think?

Comment: It is possible to do it as shown in the link that I have shared above but it is definitely not advisable to do that.

Comment: Friendly hint: AFAIK the `AddComment` syntax refers to a *method* (e.g. `a.AddComment Text`), not to an assignment via `=`:  - c.f. [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.addcomment).  BTW The individual worksheet change events could be used to *outwit* the `#VALUE` error, e.g. via `If IsError(Target) Then Target = Checkdate(Target)`, though I'd not recommend that :-;

Comment: @T.M. `AddComment syntax refers to a method` Yup. The link that I posted in my comment not only talks about the MS Help but also about updating a worksheet (Not assignment) and also about changing a comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - thx for reply; I referred to pure syntax in the 1st part of comment: AFAIK the `.AddComment` code is followed immediately by a (variant) text, not by an inserted equal sign ("="); `a.AddComment = "Remotely available"` would result in Error 1004 ("Application-defined or object-defined error"). Do I miss something here?

Comment: `a.AddComment = "Remotely available" would result in Error 1004` I do not get that error. The comment is added as shown in the screenshot. Or have i misunderstood you? @T.M.

Comment: @T.M. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207118/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-t-m).

Comment: @MiraçMertPelister: You may want to see the recent edit in my post?